# Who is "הנגד" that the Ramban is referring to?

Tags: historical-figures, parashat-lech-lecha, ramban

The [Ramban in Sefer Bereishis, Perek 17, Passuk 1](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01583.html#HtmpReportNum0016_L2), ד״ה א-ל שקי quotes Rebbi Avraham (the Ibn Ezra) who says something in the name of ״הנגד״ .
The words of the Ramban are: ״ורבי אברהם יפרשו בשם **הנגד זכרונו לברכה.**

Who exactly is this Hanagid? What is his name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our version of the Ibn Ezra actually does not have him quoting anyone, but rather saying that idea in the name of many.

The Rav Kook edition of the Ibn Ezra has second section with a variant text which does find him quoting this in the name of The Nagid. The footnote there says this is indeed a reference to Rabi Shmuel Hanagid, and sends us to the introduction section of the seffer where all the people quoted by the Ibn Ezra are mentioned.

There is a list there of all eight times Ibn Ezra quotes Rabi Shmuel Hanagid.

Bereishis 19,18. 33,10. 49,18. 49,23.

Shemos 6,3. 32,31.

Bamidbar 22,7.

Bereishis variant text 17,1.

Comment: From Just that first reference Bereishis 19,18 it should be clear that this footnote is correct.

Answer (score 4):

He is quoting [Rabbi Shmuel Hanagid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ibn_Naghrillah). Rabbi Shmuel HaNagid, also called just HaNagid, was a major religious and political figure in Spain just after the year 1000 CE.